# in a MEAN.js stack, where can i configure the jshint warnings?

Tags: node.js, express, jshint, meanjs

im developing a mean-stack based application, and suddenly im getting 750 errors in 150 pages because of jshint, none of these errors create a problem in the sense that the code is breaking, so this huge list just junks up my console with warnings that 'require' is undefined.

i know this is somewhat of a stupid question but ive been looking for hours and i dont find any file that resembles something that i can work with.

where are the jshint configuration files in a mean.js stack based application? what is the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `.jshintrc` file. jshint will obey rules defined in a `.jshintrc` file in a root directory and it will also apply any rule overrides defined in `.jshintrc` files found in your project's subdirectories.

The format looks like this:

```
{
    "bitwise"       : false,    // Prohibit bitwise operators (&, |, ^, etc.).
    "curly"         : true,     // Require {} for every new block or scope.
    "eqeqeq"        : true      // Require triple equals i.e. `===`.
}
```

The full set of options are defined here: http://jshint.com/docs/options/